# PHP Page expiration issue

Tags: redirect

Currently, I have:

```
    header('Refresh: 300;url="http://www.ohjustthatguy.com/uploads/"');
$_SESSION['refresh'] = 'true';
```

This is a timer to redirect the browser after 5 minutes of inactivity, and sets the `$_SESSION` variable to true, so that the /uploads/index.html page picks it up and displays some extra text. The problem is is that if you hit the back button without any page expiration, the `$_SESSION` variable still gets set, and therefore the text still gets displayed.

Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

Comment: _PHP_ should probably be a tag on your question, not part of the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Javascript an option for you? If it is, it might be a better way to handle the timeout (and you could do more sophisticated 'inactivity' tracking if you wanted).

Alternatively, you could add it as a GET parameter: `header('Refresh: 300;url="http://www.ohjustthatguy.com/uploads/?refresh=true"');`

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks! I will also definitely look into JavaScript. I know the basics, but I will look into inactivity tracking. Thanks!